# Full GC do not seem execute (out of memory)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, out-of-memory, jvm-hotspot

I have 2 web servers (4 cores / 16 GB RAM / Cent OS 7) behind a load balancer using round robin algorithm.

Applications are build with `Java using Apache/Tomcat`.

Servers, Apache, Tomcat and Webapps have the same configuration, with the `heap size : -Xms12840m -Xmx12840m`

The problem is that the 1st server goes through an out of memory. Kernel kill the java process because of an out of memory. While the 2nd server is more stable.

I tried to monitor and analyse the Heap dump memory using VisualVM and also the GC with jstat.

About the heap dump memory, I didn't found any memory leak, which does not mean that there are not.
But with `VisualJM / Monitor` I can observe that a Full GC is done on the 2nd server when the old generation is full. Which is not the case on the 1st server. In fact, it seems the first server is constantly more busy than the second despite of the round robin algorithm used by the load balancer.
So, on the 1st server it seems that the JVM has not the time to proceed to a full GC before the out of memory.

By default, the ratio between the young/old generation is 1:2

Minor GC on the young generation are ok, when the Eden if full a minor GC is done. But when the old generation growth near the 100%, there is no Full GC.

So, how can I optimise the GC in order to avoid the out of memory ?
Why the full GC is not done on server 1 ? 
Is it because of a peak of requests on the server and then the JVM is not able to proceed a full GC in time ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which collector do you use? What is the reason that trigger Full GC? Is the configuration of the two servers the same?

Comment: I did not specify a collector. And I did not verify which one is used by default (By the way how to do that ?). Like I said in my first message, the configuration of 2 servers is the same. And the problem is I don't know the reason the Full GC is not trigger on  the 1st server leading to the OOM.

Comment: When you say that the kernel kills the Java process, it’s not a JVM issue at all. The kernel’s reason to kill a process are not necessarily a GC trigger within a process’ JVM. Perhaps an issue of overcommitted memory.

Comment: If you get a kernel OOM kill, it means that your `Xmx` setting is too high and the JVM tries to use more memory than is available on your server. Are you sure there are no difference in other software running next to the JVM?

Comment: Gilles, when you say Xmx is too high, too high compared to what (Physical RAM=16GB)  ?

Comment: The total amount of the memory allocated by all processed, compared to the actually available memory. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment • https://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html • http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/ • https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first etc.